# How to load file to linkedlist c programming

Tags: c, file, linked-list

This is only part of my whole code, all works fine, save function works fine, but when I load the file, *it only can retrieve 1 records from the file*, and when I load it and save while there is no file, *it will create empty data first in the record*, should i send the entire code?

Sorry, I'm still new, that's why I only do what my lecture say, she use fflush stdin, gets and stuff, I still don't know which is better keywords to change it. thx

```
void savefile()
{
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("airrecord.txt","w");
curr=start;
while(curr)
{
    fprintf(fp, "Booking ID      = %10s\n",curr->booking_id);
    fprintf(fp, "Seat Number     = %10s\n",curr->seatno);
    fprintf(fp, "Name            = %10s\n",curr->name);
    fprintf(fp, "Passport Number = %10s\n",curr->passno);
    fputc('\n',fp);
    curr=curr->next;
}
fclose(fp);
}

void loadfile()
{
FILE *fp =fopen("airrecord.txt","r");
int c;

while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    curr=start;

    if(start==NULL)
    {
        start=curr=(struct passenger *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct passenger));
        fscanf(fp, "Booking ID      = %10s\n",curr->booking_id);
        fscanf(fp, "Seat Number     = %10s\n",curr->seatno);
        fscanf(fp, "Name            = %10s\n",curr->name);
        fscanf(fp, "Passport Number = %10s\n",curr->passno);
        curr->next=NULL;
        break;
    }

        while(curr->next=NULL)
            curr=curr->next;

        curr->next=(struct passenger *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct passenger));
        curr=curr->next;

        fscanf(fp, "Booking ID      = %10s\n",curr->booking_id);
        fscanf(fp, "Seat Number     = %10s\n",curr->seatno);
        fscanf(fp, "Name            = %10s\n",curr->name);
        fscanf(fp, "Passport Number = %10s\n",curr->passno);
        curr->next=NULL;
        break;

}
fclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
FILE *fp;
void reserve_seat(), cancel_seat(), modify_seat(), display_layout(), exit();
int choice;
start=curr=NULL;
loadfile();


do
{

    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n*************************************************");
    printf("\n\n**************AIRLINE RESERVATION MENU***********");
    printf("\n\n*************************************************");
    printf("\n\n* 1. Reserve seat\t\t\t\t*");
    printf("\n\n* 2. Modify seat\t\t\t\t*");
    printf("\n\n* 3. Cancel seat\t\t\t\t*");
    printf("\n\n* 4. Display seat layout\t\t\t*");
    printf("\n\n* 5. save and exit Exit\t\t\t\t\t*");
    printf("\n\n*************************************************");
    printf("\n\n\tEnter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);fflush(stdin);
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        reserve_seat();
        break;

    case 2:
        modify_seat();
        break;

    case 3:
        cancel_seat();
        break;

    case 4:
        display_layout();
        break;
    case 5:
        {
        savefile();
        break;
        }
    default:
        printf("invalid choice!!, please try again");
    }
    getch();

}while (choice != 5);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `break` statement in the end of the `if(start==NULL)` condition block inside the `loadfile()` function will exit the loop so you will read just the first record.

Note also that `while(curr->next=NULL)` is probably not what you want and you need to replace the `=` with `==`.

Comment: instead of break should i use return?, or just remove the break?

Comment: what should i change in the curr->next=null?

Comment: I am sorry but it is impossible to teach C in the comments. I strongly advice you to go through [K&R](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-Brian-W-Kernighan/dp/0131103628) or to read a good C tutorial to understand better the basic language constructs. `break` statement will terminate the execution of the nearest enclosing loop which is not what you want because you want to exit the loop only after reading the whole file. You should change `while(curr->next=NULL)` to `while(curr->next==NULL)` because `==` is for comparison and `=` is for assignment.